# when 2 consecutive actions lead to the same <from-outcome>outcomestring<from-outcome>, hence same page, the second one doesn't respond

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am facing this weird issue in 12C JDEV:

I have such definitions in adfc-config.xml:

```
<view id="mystring">
    <page>page_a.jspx</page>
    <view-id>page_a.jspx</view-id>
    <redirect/>
  </view>
<control-flow-case>
  <from-outcome>mystring</from-outcome>
  <to-activity-id>mystring</to-activity-id>
</control-flow-case>
```

and the page associated to this "mystring" is page_a.jspx.

When clicking on 2 menus which actions both lead to the above "mystring", hence page_a.jspx, the second menu seems not responding at all. When debugging, it shows that in the controller class associated to the page_a.jspx, the second visit is considered as a "postBack" since "isPostBack()" in onPagePreRender() returns true. This appears to be the reason that the second time, page_a.jspx is not reloaded at all(if reloaded, some texts will be updated for the second time). To verify that,I simply refreshed the same page_a.jspx after second click, and the page_a.jspx got updated with texts expected.

So my question, is this a expected behavior or not by design of ADF? Either way, is there a workaround to get the second visit to reload the page?

Thanks,
Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find an answer myself: in the controller class' onPagePreRender() method, refresh the whole page_a.jspx (sample codes taken from this url: http://adfblogspot.blogspot.ca/2012/06/how-to-reload-whole-jsfjspx-page-from.html):

```
public String refreshPage_action() {  
    FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    String pageToRefresh = fctx.getViewRoot().getViewId();   //getting View Id of current page  
    ViewHandler viewHandler = fctx.getApplication().getViewHandler();      
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = viewHandler.createView(fctx, pageToRefresh);   //ViewRoot for current page  
    viewRoot.setViewId(pageToRefresh);  
    fctx.setViewRoot(viewRoot);     //set the viewroot in facesContext to reload  
    return null;  
 }
```

controller class:

```
public void onPagePreRender() {
    super.onPagePreRender();
// do you data update then call refreshPage_action()
}
```

this force the page reloaded everytime.